# Adding arguments when creating a function in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. For example i have a function called w whose code is listed below:

```
    w<-function(x){
       a<-x+2
       plot(a)
      }
```

How can i add these arguments in the function so that

1. Export: a number equal to 0 if result should be allowed on screen and to 1 if the result should be printed in a text file.
2. Tfile: name of the text file where the results will be written to;
3. Gfile:name of the pdf file where the graph will be written to.

Comment: `function(x,export,tfile,gfile)` ?

Answer (score 4):

To include further arguments in a function, simply list them in `function()`.

```
w <- function(x, export, tfile, gfile) {
    a <- x + 2
    if (export == 1) {
        write.csv(a, file = tfile)
    } else if (export == 0) {
        pdf(file = gfile)
        plot(a)
        dev.off()
    }
}
```

For more information on writing and debugging functions in R, see [this article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-and-debug-an-r-function/).

Answer (score -1):

As the others have pointed out, just separate additional arguments with commas. You can have as many as you want.

```
w <- function(x, export, tfile, gfile)
```

Assigning values within the function definition allows them to have default arguments, so you can choose not to include them

```
w <- function(x, export = 0, tfile = "w.csv", gfile = "w.pdf")
```

I will add that a handy thing for `plot` functions (and many other functions) is the ellipsis `...` construct, which basically means "any other relevant arguments". For instance, doing something like this allows you to optionally pass further graphical parameters to your plot (e.g. label names, title).

```
w <- function(x, ...){
    a <- x + 2
    plot(a, ...)
}
w(10, main="Main title")
w(15, type='l', col='red')
```

Comment: The OP specified that `export` takes values 1 and 0 rather than `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Also, your last example won't run since you haven't enclosed both the definition of `a` and the call to `plot()` in brackets; `a` will be undefined when you try to plot it.

Comment: My mistake! Both have been fixed. Although to be fair, the way R evaluates logical statements (like the one in your post), `FALSE` and `0` are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, they do have the same effect, and indeed I would generally prefer to use a logical value in this context. (Btw, not the downvoter, though I probably would have posted this as a comment rather than an answer.)

Comment: I agree about the comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet to post comments on posts other than my own (need 50, but I have 49...).